# Replace only Even occurrences of re.sub() - Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am scraping a website which has really poor HTML structure and I am getting text like this

Example:

```
Creator:
\r\r
My Name
\r\r
Date created:
\r\r
123123
<br><br>
Title:
\r\r
Title here
\r\r
```

I want it to look like

```
Creator: My Name
\r\r
Date created:123123
Title:Title here
\r\r
```

I have this regex `_str = re.sub('\r+','',_str)` But I know its wrong because it replaces all `\r`

Is there any way to iterate over `re.sub()`? Or you have any idea in mind  how do I achieve my goal?

Comment: Try    _str = re.sub('([^\r]+)\r\r([^\r]+\r\r)', '\\1\\2', _str)

Comment: Check this relevant post http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/131057

Answer (score 3):

You should try something like replacing :

```
:
\r\r
```

by `:`

Comment: What you want is when you have a `:`, remove the `\r` after, if you do this : `re.sub('[:]\r+',':',_str)` That should do this :<br>

Comment: I failed sorry, so that should change `Name:\r\rMy_Name\r\r` to `Name:My_Name\r\r`

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `\r\r` pattern + next group (including next `\r\r` pattern) by only the second part.

```
re.sub('\r+([^\r]+\r+)',r'\1',_str)
```

(I would have liked to do it with forward lookup but here you *have* to consume the following pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be regex?

```
s1 = 'Creator:\r\rMy Name\r\rDate created:\r\r123123<br><br>Title:\r\rTitle here\r\r'
s2 = ''.join(l + '\r\r' * (n % 3 == 1) for n, l in enumerate(s1.split('\r\r')))
// s2 == 'Creator:My Name\r\rDate created:123123<br><br>Title:Title here\r\r'
```